# Laravel batch file upload

Tags: laravel-5

I have a csv file with the following structure:

`id,title,sub_title,filename
1,Title 1, Sub Title 1,filename_1.mp3
2,Title 2, Sub Title 2,filename_2.mp3
3,Title 3, Sub Title 3,filename_3.mp3
(...)`

I'm loading the CSV file inside a App\Console\Command (artisan command).
Assuming the files exist on the filesystem and the path is correct, for each csv line how can I upload the related file and validate it using the Validator class?

I'm using this code:

```
$validator = Validator::make(array('filename' => 'path_to_filename_x.mp3'), [
    'filename' => 'required|file|audio:mp3,wav,ogg',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($validator->errors());
    echo '</pre>';
    die();
```

}

I'm getting the error:
"The attribute must be a file."
Because I'm sending text instead of a resource (i suppose).

How can I upload these files without using a form using Laravel 5.6?

Thks!

Comment: If file path is there you can use the file_get_contents() and file_put_contents() method to upload files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question: **how can I upload the related file and validate it using the Validator class?**

Validating the files:

Create a custom rule in laravel and there you can add logic like.

```
if(file_exists($path)){

   //check for file type

}
```

Upload the files :

use `$fcontent = file_get_contents($filepath)` and `file_put_contents($newfilepath, $fcontent)`